# Why nodejs restarts every time I refresh the page on the client side

Tags: node.js

I am new to nodejs and did some test on my nodejs app. The code is basically like this.

```js
import express from 'express';

import jsonfile from "jsonfile";

const app = express();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3002;
let global=0;
app.use(express.static(`${__dirname}/assets`));
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  //write file
  const file = '/path/data.json';

  var obj = {
    name:'cd'
  };
  jsonfile.writeFile(file,obj,{spaces: 2}, (err)=>{
    console.error(err);
  })
  next();
})

app.get('/test', (req, res, next) => {
  global++
  res.send(''+global);
})
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`App listening on port ${PORT}!`);
});
```

I built it on localhost, and input http://localhost:3002/test into the browser. The app will send the *global* counter to the browser, but if I refresh the page, I found my nodejs app restart and the counter doesn't change. If I comment out the jsonfile.writeFile part and do the same process like before, the nodejs app won't restart and the counter will increase every time I refresh the page. Why is that?

Comment: *Restarts* as in? Throws an error then restarts? Using `nodemon` or similar for app start?

Comment: no err, the log always said the err is null.  If I use the writeFile part, every time I refresh the page on the browser, I can see that nodejs log the `App listening on port 3002` again immediately. I use nodemon for starting the app.

Comment: I would not use `global` as a variable name for starters. That's actually reserved.

Comment: Paste the terminal output so we can see what commands are running and all of their output.

Comment: Nodemon will generally tell you why it's restarting. What is the console output right before `App listening on port 3002` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've commented the `nodemon` forces the page reload (live reload) to enable you to see the changes instantly.

Use `node <your_script_name.js>` or `node <any_command_defined_in_scripts>` (whatever is applicable) instead of `nodemon` if you don't want auto-refresh every time when you refresh the page.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Nodemon only restarts node when it crashes. It should not affect a running node process in any way.

Comment: @skypecakes But as per the description given in the `nodemon.io` official website, **Nodemon is a utility that will monitor for any changes in your source and automatically restart your server. Perfect for development. Install it using npm.**

Comment: Ah! Good point. So you're saying that nodemon must be monitoring `/path/data.json`, and therefore whenever that file is written to, it restarts the server.

Comment: Yeah, it could be. I found it said '[nodemon] restarting due to changes...', the only possible change is from writing to file.

Comment: Note that you can [exclude](https://github.com/remy/nodemon#ignoring-files) files from watch list instead of dropping `nodemon`

Comment: @GabrielBleu I try to exclude the file according the reference, but after I input the ignore command, it will do 'node index.js'. The problem is that I use es6 so it can't start node index.js directly, so how can I exclude the file? I normally start the app by using ''nodemon --exec babel-node src/index.js" .